# First answer users copying answer from other user

Tags: discussion, answers

Happened twice to me.

I work on the answer while somebody post first answer. I check it and see if it's still worth to post mine. I believe my answer is better so I post it few minutes later.

I come back few hours later and I see negative score, and first answer edited to look almost like mine being up voted.

Both scenarios I deleted my answer to not look like I just copy/paste first answer.

Both times I din't tag the answer because I didn't see a point as I would be mostly the only one to do so.

Is this action prohibited in any way? And are there any steps to prevent it?

Update:

@Raju this is what I see

[image]

Comment: Plagiarism is not allowed in SO. If he copies your idea into his answer, You can custom flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: However, if it's just the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) there isn't really anything to be done.

Comment: I was thinking about, but I won't leave my answer since is downvoted, and deletion of proper answer is not beneficial to community.

Comment: It's not wise to be hyper-sensitive to a single downvote. If it's your work and you believe it's correct, stand by your answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't want to look like copycat, plus to someone who started as recent as I did getting every reputation point counts.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It didn't do for me back when I started. If you know your stuff and are active your reputation is going to grow automatically. (I can relate to deleting an answer that doesn't add anything to the other answers, though. A more productive way to solve the problem than deleting your answer is to edit it again and adding more detail/references if possible!)

Comment: @Claudius, You are the first one to present that idea if first answerer edits his post. If the first answerer edits his post, timestamp will change. If you place your cursor on the answered date, you can see exact time when it was edited. Also, You can educate him, by putting a comment that it is not fair copy someone else idea. Some times, it works. People correct themselves.

Comment: @Raju you mean edited x minutes/hours ago? because answered timestamp seems the same. I would investigate this more. Thanks.

Comment: @Claudius, Place the cursor on top of text like '[answered 20 days ago](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LzZS7.png)'.

Comment: @Raju please see update, This is how I see it.

Comment: @Claudius The edit history on the other answer will show the time it was created and the time of any subsequent edits (unless they were within the 5 minute grace period). Look at the "edited ..." link under this question for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any post update will be tracked under revisions (exception: Grace periods).

In your case, if the previous answer is edited, then you will see a link, 'edited xyz min ago'. That's the link to revisions made on that post. It will give the necessary details like what text edited, when it was edited, etc.

[image: Link to edit revision]

For example, when I click on 'edited May10 at 2:32' link, it shows the revisions like below.

[image: Revision history]

Provide your answer link and other answer's revision link in Custom mod flag. It's worth flagging only if that user does this very frequently.

I suggest you to put a comment on his post and explain why it is not right to do.

On the other side, you can improve your post with more data, more examples, images, etc.